# How to disable Primefaces calendar date picker when using key board for accessibility

Tags: primefaces, accessibility

I need to disable Primefaces calendars date picker when i.e. tabbed in to. In otherwords when the calendar element is accesed via keyboard, the date picker cannot be shown for accessibility. How to implement this?

My primefaces calendar element:

```
              <div class="calendarDatepicker">
                <p:outputLabel for="cdp" value="Date"/>
                <p:calendar id="cdp" value="#{myController.cdp} required="true" pt:aria-describedby="aria-tooltip2"/>

                <div id="aria-tooltip2" aria-hidden="false" class="aria-hidden">#{acc.tooltipCdp}</div>
                <p:tooltip for="dat" value="#{acc.tooltipCpd}" position="right"/>
              </div>
```

Comment: Which is your PF version? I would try with js, intercepting tab pressed and when your calendar is focused close the date picker.

Comment: `p:calendar` is deprecated

Comment: @WoAiNii PM version is 8.0. I don't like mixing JS to JSF out of principle, but you might be right it might be the easiest or perhast the only way to implement this.

Comment: @JasperdeVries What component should I use instead?

Comment: @WScoder the replacement component is DatePicker written by PF from scratch instead of the old Jquery Calendar.  Look on the PF showcase for DatePicker.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4685